# SQL Server round up to 0.5 multiple

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I round up the values to the multiples of 0.5 in SQL Server.

I tried using `CEILING`, `ROUND` and `CASE` functions.

Comment: Give some example with your expected output also mention that what you have already tried.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What you're asking isn't completely clear.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: What is the source data type? What do you expect for edge cases/boundaries, like 2.24999 and 2.25. Normal math rules or ... something else? `ROUND` and `CEILING` both exist because they're not identical, and I'm not sure what `CASE` has to do with it, but showing your attempts (and what you expected) would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
ROUND(<value> * 2, 0) / 2
```

So, you multiply the input value by 2, rounding it to the nearest integer, then dividing it by 2 to get to the nearest multiple of 0.5

Answer (score 0):

To round up to the nearest 0.5 double, then take the ceiling then divide by 2.

```
declare @n decimal(12,4) = 12.0

select ceiling(2.0*@n)/2.0
```